# UWP Speech Recognizer's ContinuousRecognitionSession not working

Tags: windows-10, uwp, speech-recognition

Below is the code that I am using in my UWP app page loading event to start a continuous recognition session but the ResultGenerated event never gets fired:

```
            SpeechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
            await SpeechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
            bool PermissionGained = await CheckMicrophonePermission();
            if (PermissionGained)
            {
                SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=
                    async (s, e1) =>
                    {
                        if ((e1.Result != null))
                        {
                            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                async () =>
                                {
                                    SpeechText.Text = e1.Result.Text;
                                });
                        }
                    };

                await SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
```

I made it to work by doing small changes. I registered the continuousRecognitionSession.Completed event, below the above code:

```
     SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
```

In the handler, I called StartAsync again as below:

```
     private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args)
     {
            await SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
     }
```

In this way code works fine but I want to find out why it does not recognize in the first case or what is wrong with that code.

Comment: Tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/enable-continuous-dictation says you need to check state first before running StartAsync, maybe it's the case

Comment: Where did you put your first code block? I tested it in the Initialization of `SpeechRecognizer` then call this initialization in `OnNavigatedTo` method, it can work. But I agree with @Nikolay, it's better to check the `SpeechRecognizerState` before start listening.

Comment: @Grace, I have put the code in    Page_Loaded event of a xaml page.

Comment: @Nikolay I had tried doing that checking the state before calling    StartAsync but that doesn't help. That would also mean that if the state is not idle     ContinuousRecognitionSession would not start at all.

Comment: That makes no difference, what is your OS version? I tested that on PC with OS 10586.

Comment: I am using OS 10240.